# pi_face_tracker installation problem

Tags: ros, kinect, face-recognition, face-detection

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am running Ubuntu 10.04 and ROS Diamondback.

Following the instructions of Patrick Goebel's `pi_face_tracker` available [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/pi_face_tracker), I get stuck compiling the `pi_vision` stack. From what I understand, the dependency `arbotix_python` of `pi_arbotix` was not found. Below is the full error.

```
rosmake --rosdep-install pi_vision

[ rosmake ] Packages requested are: ['pi_vision']                               
[ rosmake ] Logging to directory/home/gsaponaro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110613-194331
[ rosmake ] Expanded args ['pi_vision'] to:
['pi_kinect', 'pi_opencv', 'pi_arbotix', 'pi_ax12_controller', 'pi_description', 'pi_speech', 'pi_turtlebot', 'pi_slam', 'pi_arm_kinematics', 'pi_actions', 'ros2opencv', 'pi_face_tracker']
[ rosmake ] Generating Install Script using rosdep then executing. This may take a minute, you will be prompted for permissions. . .
Failed to find stack for package [arbotix_python]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [arbotix_python]:Cannot locate installation of package arbotix_python: [rospack] couldn't find package [arbotix_python]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [ax12_controller_core]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [ax12_controller_core]:Cannot locate installation of package ax12_controller_core: [rospack] couldn't find package [ax12_controller_core]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [joint_state_publisher]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [joint_state_publisher]:Cannot locate installation of package joint_state_publisher: [rospack] couldn't find package [joint_state_publisher]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [pocketsphinx]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [pocketsphinx]:Cannot locate installation of package pocketsphinx: [rospack] couldn't find package [pocketsphinx]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [sound_play]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [sound_play]:Cannot locate installation of package sound_play: [rospack] couldn't find package [sound_play]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [kinematics_msgs]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [kinematics_msgs]:Cannot locate installation of package kinematics_msgs: [rospack] couldn't find package [kinematics_msgs]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
Failed to find stack for package [arm_kinematics]
Failed to load rosdep.yaml for package [arm_kinematics]:Cannot locate installation of package arm_kinematics: [rospack] couldn't find package [arm_kinematics]. ROS_ROOT[/opt/ros/diamondback/ros] ROS_PACKAGE_PATH[/home/gsaponaro/kinect/ros:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks]
rosdep executing this script:
{{{
set -o errexit
#No Packages to install
}}}
[ rosmake ] rosdep successfully installed all system dependencies               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosbuild [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosbuild ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbuild
 No Makefile in package rosbuild
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> cpp_common [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< cpp_common ROS_NOBUILD in package cpp_common           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> roslib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< roslib ROS_NOBUILD in package roslib                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> xmlrpcpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> roslang [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp_traits [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rostime [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< roslang ROS_NOBUILD in package roslang
 No Makefile in package roslang
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< xmlrpcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package xmlrpcpp               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rostime ROS_NOBUILD in package rostime                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp_traits ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_traits     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> std_msgs [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roscpp_serialization [ make ]                          
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosconsole [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roscpp_serialization ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp_serialization
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< std_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package std_msgs               
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosconsole ROS_NOBUILD in package rosconsole           
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosgraph_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosgraph_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph_msgs     
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> tinyxml [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< tinyxml ROS_NOBUILD in package tinyxml                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> bond [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< bond ROS_NOBUILD in package bond                       
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> smclib [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< smclib ROS_NOBUILD in package smclib                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pluginlib [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> roscpp [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rospy [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< roscpp ROS_NOBUILD in package roscpp                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pluginlib ROS_NOBUILD in package pluginlib             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rospy ROS_NOBUILD in package rospy                     
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosclean [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> bondcpp [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosclean ROS_NOBUILD in package rosclean               
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< bondcpp ROS_NOBUILD in package bondcpp                 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosgraph [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosgraph ROS_NOBUILD in package rosgraph               
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> nodelet [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< nodelet ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet                 
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> rosmaster [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< rosmaster ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmaster             
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosout [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosout ROS_NOBUILD in package rosout                   
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosunit [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosunit ROS_NOBUILD in package rosunit                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> openni [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< openni ROS_NOBUILD in package openni                   
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> eigen [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< eigen ROS_NOBUILD in package eigen                     
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> angles [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< angles ROS_NOBUILD in package angles                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roslaunch [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roslaunch ROS_NOBUILD in package roslaunch
 No Makefile in package roslaunch
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosnode [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosnode ROS_NOBUILD in package rosnode                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> cminpack [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rostest [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rostest ROS_NOBUILD in package rostest                 
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< cminpack ROS_NOBUILD in package cminpack               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> flann [ make ]                                         
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< flann ROS_NOBUILD in package flann                     
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> nite [ make ]                                          
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> topic_tools [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> message_filters [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> bullet [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package topic_tools         
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< nite ROS_NOBUILD in package nite                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< bullet ROS_NOBUILD in package bullet                   
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< message_filters ROS_NOBUILD in package message_filters 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> rosbag [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< rosbag ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbag                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> kdl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosbagmigration [ make ]                               
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rosmsg [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> nodelet_topic_tools [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< kdl ROS_NOBUILD in package kdl                         
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< nodelet_topic_tools ROS_NOBUILD in package nodelet_topic_tools
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosbagmigration ROS_NOBUILD in package rosbagmigration
 No Makefile in package rosbagmigration
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rosmsg ROS_NOBUILD in package rosmsg
 No Makefile in package rosmsg
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> opencv2 [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< opencv2 ROS_NOBUILD in package opencv2                 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> rostopic [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> yaml_cpp [ make ]                                      
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< rostopic ROS_NOBUILD in package rostopic               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< yaml_cpp ROS_NOBUILD in package yaml_cpp               
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> geometry_msgs [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> rosservice [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< geometry_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package geometry_msgs     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< rosservice ROS_NOBUILD in package rosservice           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> diagnostic_msgs [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< diagnostic_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_msgs 
[rosmake-0] Starting >>> pi_arbotix [ make ]                                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> sensor_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> dynamic_reconfigure [ make ]                           
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> roswtf [ make ]                                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< dynamic_reconfigure ROS_NOBUILD in package dynamic_reconfigure
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< sensor_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package sensor_msgs         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> diagnostic_updater [ make ]                            
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> image_transport [ make ]                               
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< roswtf ROS_NOBUILD in package roswtf                   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> stereo_msgs [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< image_transport ROS_NOBUILD in package image_transport 
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> tf [ make ]                                            
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< diagnostic_updater ROS_NOBUILD in package diagnostic_updater
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< stereo_msgs ROS_NOBUILD in package stereo_msgs         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl [ make ]                                           
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< tf ROS_NOBUILD in package tf                           
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> openni_tracker [ make ]                                
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> cv_bridge [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl                         
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pcl_ros [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< cv_bridge ROS_NOBUILD in package cv_bridge             
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< openni_tracker ROS_NOBUILD in package openni_tracker   
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> camera_calibration_parsers [ make ]                    
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> self_test [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pcl_ros ROS_NOBUILD in package pcl_ros                 
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> openni_camera [ make ]                                 
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< self_test ROS_NOBUILD in package self_test             
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> driver_base [ make ]                                   
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< camera_calibration_parsers ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_calibration_parsers
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> camera_info_manager [ make ]                           
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< openni_camera ROS_NOBUILD in package openni_camera     
[rosmake-2] Starting >>> pi_kinect [ make ]                                     
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< camera_info_manager ROS_NOBUILD in package camera_info_manager
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< driver_base ROS_NOBUILD in package driver_base         
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> uvc_cam [ make ]                                       
[rosmake-3] Starting >>> pi_ax12_controller [ make ]                            
[ rosmake ] All 32 linesi_arbotix: 0.6 sec ] [ pi... [ 4 Active 64/81 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  [rosbuild] Building package pi_arbotix
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests pi_arbotix
  [rospack] couldn't find dependency [arbotix_python] of [pi_arbotix]
  [rospack] missing dependency
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package 'pi_arbotix'.
    Look above for errors from rospack itself.  Aborting.  Please fix the
    broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pi_arbotix written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/gsaponaro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110613-194331/pi_arbotix/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< pi_arbotix [FAIL] [ 0.68 seconds ]                     
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pi_arbotix. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] All 32 linesi_kinect: 0.7 sec ] [ uvc... [ 3 Active 64/81 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  mkdir -p bin
  cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
  -- The C compiler identification is GNU
  -- The CXX compiler identification is GNU
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
  -- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
  -- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
  -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
  [rosbuild] Building package pi_ax12_controller
  Failed to invoke /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rospack deps-manifests pi_ax12_controller
  [rospack] couldn't find dependency [ax12_controller_core] of [pi_ax12_controller]
  [rospack] missing dependency
  
  
  CMake Error at /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:113 (message):
    
  
    Failed to invoke rospack to get compile flags for package
    'pi_ax12_controller'.  Look above for errors from rospack itself.
    Aborting.  Please fix the broken dependency!
  
  Call Stack (most recent call first):
    /opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:183 (rosbuild_invoke_rospack)
    CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)
  
  
  -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package pi_ax12_controller written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/gsaponaro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110613-194331/pi_ax12_controller/build_output.log
[rosmake-3] Finished <<< pi_ax12_controller [FAIL] [ 0.79 seconds ]             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package pi_ax12_controller. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< uvc_cam [PASS] [ 1.11 seconds ]                        
[rosmake-2] Finished <<< pi_kinect [PASS] [ 7.37 seconds ]                      
[ rosmake ] Results:                                                            
[ rosmake ] Built 68 packages with 2 failures.                                  
[ rosmake ] Summary output to directory                                         
[ rosmake ] /home/gsaponaro/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20110613-194331
```

Thank you very much for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10243/pi_face_tracker-installation-problem/) by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2011-06-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Many thanks to Fergs for bringing this to my attention.  I somehow completely messed up the pi-robot-ros-pkg repository this morning just before leaving the computer for several hours.  I have restored the pi_face_tracker package.  In fact, I restored it to version 0.2 which I was just about to release anyway.  There are a copy of bug fixes and pair of new features as listed in the ChangeLog.text file and reproduced below.  In the meantime, I will work on restoring the rest of the repository...

Release Notes for Version 0.2

- Fixed bug in add_features() function that prevented adding of new features(!)
- Fixed bug that caused occasional ROI to be defined outside boundaries of image frame.
- Added new parameter "feature_type" which can be set to 0 for Good Features To Track (default) or 1 for SURF features.
- Added new parameter "use_depth_for_tracking" which causes points to be pruned if their depth value is too far from the currently tracked cloud.
- Changed mask shape from ellipse to rectangle for manually-selected regions; i.e. ellipse-shaped mask only used when parameter auto_face_tracking is set to True.
- Changed default image display window size for ros2opencv from 320x240 to 640x480.

Release Notes for Version 0.1

- Initial release.

---

Originally posted by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) with karma: 4046 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Giovanni Saponaro](https://answers.ros.org/users/595/giovanni-saponaro/) on 2011-06-13**:
Thank you, re-installing the pi_vision stack from scratch worked.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can checkout the arbotix stack via SVN: http://www.ros.org/wiki/arbotix, which contains arbotix_python (note you may also need to make arbotix_msgs within that stack).

However, it would actually appear that the problem is a recent commit. It looks like ros_by_example may have been put in the wrong place, and so a number of a packages other than vision related are now under pi_vision. You might try running 'make clean', deleting the ros_by_example directory, and then running your rosmake command.

One other possibility is to checkout the tagged release: svn co http://pi-robot-ros-pkg.googlecode.com/svn/tags/pi_vision/0.1.1 pi_vision

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2011-06-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1